# Setting up a relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to set up a one to many relationship in Entity Framework Core using the Fluent API with no success.

I have two objects called Message and Source and are defined as

```
public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FromUserID { get; set; }
    public int ToUserID { get; set; }
    public int SourceID { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeDelivered { get; set; }
    public Source Source { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

with one message relating to one source and one source relating to many messages.

In my context class I then have the following

```
public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
```

and then define the relationship as

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne<Source>(m => m.Source)
            .WithMany(s => s.Messages);

}
```

If I test this with the following

```
var get = context.Messages.Where(m => m.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

My problem is I get the data returned for the message OK but for source I'm only getting null.

I've looked at different tutorials and SOF questions regarding this, but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Include(msg => msg.Source)` to the query, and it will force it to load
with the message

`var get = context.Messages.Include(msg => msg.Source).Where(m => m.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to load related data:

**Eager loading:**

> means that the related data is loaded from the database as part of the initial query

**Explicit loading:**

> means that the related data is explicitly loaded from the database at a later time

**Lazy loading:**

> means that the related data is transparently loaded from the database when the navigation property is accessed

See the [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for more information.

If we go with the lazy loading approach, you can set your options with UseLazyLoadingProxies():

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

...and then make your navigation properties virtual:

```
public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
```

and

```
public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm not able to see UseLazyLoadingProxies().  Am I missing a dependency?

Comment: @RichardBoyce All this is explained in the documentation link (including the proxies package)