# Entity framework relations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

im trying to make an app and got a slight problem. my structure looks like this:

```
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        private int _Id;

        public int Id {
            get { return _Id; }
            set { _Id = value; }
        }
    }

    public class SupplierModel : BaseModel
    {
        [ForeginKey("CountryCode")] // This should map to say "se" or "no" or whatever in the CountryModel table
        public virtual CountryModel Country;
    }

    public class CountryModel : BaseModel
    {
        private string _CountryCode;

        [Key] // This should be another key in the table to get the actual country. 
        public string CountryCode {
            get { return _CountryCode; }
            set { _CountryCode = value; }
        }


        private string _CountryName;

        public string CountryName {
            get { return _CountryName; }
            set { _CountryName = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now i want SupplierModel to link to CountryModel (Works fine by the Id) but i want it to be the country code to be the relationship not the Id between the Entities.

So accessing CountryModel.Country should map to the CountryModel table and pull out the one that matches the country model.

Hope i didnt mess it up totaly for you, hard to explain when i do not fully understand Entity framework and database relations .. trying to learn =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a relationship in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225093/setting-up-a-relationship-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: And what is the problem?